# JavaScript - Regular Expression that validates one +/- at begning and one decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that can validate  one +/- at begning, and one decimal point in the string using **test()** object method. Currently my regex is :
 `/[\d\b\t\+\-]|\./` which allows multiple occurences of +, -, and dot(**.**).

I need regular expression that recognize a string like:
 ***+23.24*** or ***+0.23*** or ***-23.24*** or ***-0.23***.

Please reply.

Comment: You could at least try it yourself, and come to SO only if you can't manage to do it on your own.

Comment: @Maresh Hey, I tried many times. I'm new to this. It's very disappointing that u r discouraging instead of passing a simple solution.

Comment: Well then you should rephrase your question and not say "I WANT", and paste your tries.

Comment: Maybe English isn't his first language and he couldn't find a better way to express himself + new + WTF negativity

Comment: It's not mine either. I just think that if you want other people to do your work, you could at least try to be clever about it. And yeah it's a bit negative, but it starts like that and then it's: Please code me this application for free on your spare time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic regular expression

```
/^[+-]\d+\.\d+$/
```

Explanation:

```
^     Match start of string
[+-]  Match either plus or minus
\d+   Match one or more numbers of digits
\.    Match a period, the \ escapes it since it means any character
\d+   Match one or more numbers of digits 
$     Match end of string
```

Comment: here's a link to a rubular page where you can play around with different values http://rubular.com/r/xonPIHy3xu
and if these numbers are in the middle of your text, drop the anchors (^ and $) - P.S. I know rubular uses Ruby RegExp but it works for this simple example